# How to install libav from launchpad?

Tags: software-installation, launchpad, libav

How could I install this package from launchpad on ubuntu 12.04??
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav

Answer (score 3):

That page tells you its packages:

```
ffmpeg: Multimedia player, server, encoder and transcoder (transitional package)
ffmpeg-doc: Documentation of the Libav API (transitional package)
libav-doc: Documentation of the Libav API
libav-source: Patched Libav sources
libav-tools: Multimedia player, server, encoder and transcoder
libavcodec-dev: Development files for libavcodec
libavcodec53: Libav codec library
libavdevice-dev: Development files for libavdevice
libavdevice53: Libav device handling library
libavfilter-dev: Development files for libavfilter
libavfilter2: Libav video filtering library
libavformat-dev: Development files for libavformat
libavformat53: Libav file format library
libavutil-dev: Development files for libavutil
libavutil51: Libav utility library
libpostproc-dev: Development files for libpostproc
libpostproc52: Libav video postprocessing library
libswscale-dev: Development files for libswscale
libswscale2: Libav video scaling library
```

`ffmpeg` is still used as the trasitional name for `libav`. Yes I know they're not really the same thing any more (one's a fork) but they're incorrectly named. I'm not sure you can get an old-fashioned ffmpeg build any more.

In short:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: RE: real ffmpeg, there's [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg), or you can get a more up-to-date static build [from their website](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Or you can [compile your own](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), though you should only do that if you want a feature the static builds don't have (like a decent AAC encoder).